# Is there a contract for namespace map argument of target's start method in lxml.etree.XMLParser?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, pycaption

In `lxml`, if you use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

DFXP_BASE_MARKUP = '''<tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" />'''

from lxml import etree

class X(object):
    def start(self, name, attrs, nsmap={}):
        if nsmap:
            print("{}: {}".format(etree.LXML_VERSION, dict(nsmap)))

p = etree.XMLParser(target=X())
p.feed(DFXP_BASE_MARKUP)
```

you might get different results, depending on the version of lxml, for example some of my results were:

```
(4, 4, 1, 0): {'': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml', 'tts': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling'
(4, 4, 0, 0): {'': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml', 'tts': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling'}
(4, 3, 5, 0): {None: 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml', 'tts': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling'}
(4, 3, 4, 0): {None: 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml', 'tts': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling'}
```

The problem is that the default namespace is sometimes associated with the key `''` and sometimes `None`. It looks like the behaviour changed in `lxml-4.4.0`. It seems like a rather relevant change and I can see no mention of it in the release notes.

I have actually come across this problem debugging through `pycaption` -> `beautifulsoup4` -> `lxml`. It appears that beautifulsoup produces invalid XML because of this, when used together with `>=lxml-4.4.0`. For me the solution is to use an old enough version of `lxml`, but it looks like it might be a major issue for `beautifulsoup4` for example.

Have you come across this problem? Is there any place in the documentation which specifies which key we should expect in this situation or indicates that both are allowed by the contract?

Comment: In think this is the lxml commit in question: https://github.com/lxml/lxml/commit/aefded0588d303c35f82360342111714eca7ec16

Comment: @mzjn thanks, I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1842026 I'm curious to see what the devs think about it

Comment: Related BeautifulSoup ticket: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1840141